# Error in gapfilling by row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
2015    2016    2017    2018    2019    2020    2021    2022    2023    2024    2025
0.4818                                  0.8109                                  0.9031
```

I have a dataframe of the form above. The 1st row is the header with data for the years 2015, 2020 and 2025 respectively. Other columns have nan's as misssing data. I want to interpolate by row and am using this:

```
df.fillna(axis = 1, method = 'ffill', inplace = True)
```

However, I get the error message:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2527, in fillna
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

--EDIT
Based on ajcr's comment below, the dtypes of the columns are float64
The dataframe is available as csv file here:
https://umd.box.com/s/yacl9eewvo2n9xbj9nz6dkoju5nhwxsr

How do I fix this?

Comment: This works in the latest release of pandas - you might need to upgrade your version.

Comment: I have 0.16.2 which seems to be latest stable

Comment: I just tried this in 16.2 as well and it seemed to work - can you provide any more information about you DataFrame - what are the dtypes of the columns?

Comment: The dtypes of the columns are float64

Comment: Also, the full dataframe is available as a csv file here: https://umd.box.com/s/yacl9eewvo2n9xbj9nz6dkoju5nhwxsr, thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Rather than linking to your enormous spreadsheet it would be helpful to include executable code of a small subset of you data. You have shown some of the data in your question but it's not clear to me what are the index and column names, or if you have these at all. Also, if you include the code version of your data sample it will be much easier for people to find a solution for you.

Comment: @user308827: the error you're getting implies that your DataFrame has mixed types - some of the columns are *not* float types (see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#l2657)). I'd drop the `inplace` argument (it's rarely of benefit anyway) and then the operation should work.

Comment: Thanks @ajcr, this works, can you put this as an answer? I will accept it

Comment: @user308827: have posted an answer - let me know if you'd like any more detail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting implies that your DataFrame has mixed types - perhaps you have integer columns as well as floating columns.

In any case, dropping the `inplace` argument should allow `fillna` to work across rows:

```
df.fillna(axis=1, method='ffill')
```

Comment: thanks @ajcr, this is perfect! but, I now realize that I should be doing interpolate and not ffill, I am getting an error there. If you could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682010/python-interpolate-not-working-on-rows, i will be very grateful