# Python interpolate not working on rows

Tags: python, pandas

Related to [Error in gapfilling by row in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681658/error-in-gapfilling-by-row-in-pandas), I would like to interpolate instead of using fillna. Currently, I am doing this:

```
df.ix[:,'2015':'2100'].interpolate(axis = 1, method = 'linear')
```

However, this does not seem to replace the NaN's. Any suggestion?

--EDIT
This does not seem to work either:

```
df.apply(pandas.Series.interpolate, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Can you please provide data that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Hi @Alexander, here's the data: https://umd.box.com/s/yacl9eewvo2n9xbj9nz6dkoju5nhwxsr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug (I'm using Pandas 0.16.2 with Python 3.4.3).

Using a **subset** of your data:

```
>>>df.ix[:3, '2015':'2020']
       2015  2016  2017  2018  2019      2020
0  0.001248   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.001281
1  0.009669   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.009963
2  0.020005   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.020651
```

The linear interpolation works fine and returns a new dataframe.

```
>>> df.ix[:3, '2015':'2020'].interpolate(axis=1, method='linear')
       2015      2016      2017      2018      2019      2020
0  0.001248  0.001255  0.001261  0.001268  0.001275  0.001281
1  0.009669  0.009728  0.009786  0.009845  0.009904  0.009963
2  0.020005  0.020134  0.020264  0.020393  0.020522  0.020651
3  0.025557  0.025687  0.025818  0.025949  0.026080  0.026211
```

The original is still untouched.

```
>>> df.ix[:4, '2015':'2020']
       2015  2016  2017  2018  2019      2020
0  0.001248   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.001281
1  0.009669   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.009963
2  0.020005   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.020651
3  0.025557   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.026211
4  0.060077   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.060909
```

So let's to to change it using the `inplace=True` parameter.

```
df.ix[:3, '2015':'2020'].interpolate(axis=1, method='linear', inplace=True)

>>> df.ix[:4, '2015':'2020']
       2015  2016  2017  2018  2019      2020
0  0.001248   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.001281
1  0.009669   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.009963
2  0.020005   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.020651
3  0.025557   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.026211
4  0.060077   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.06090
```

The changes didn't hold.

Comment: thanks @alexander, you are right it does seem like a bug, I am going to accept your answer because I can at least assign the R.H.S to a dataframe and that works